how to pass Type and access it through a property for use in AddDbContext
I need to create a class where I can pass in a type who derives from DbContext. I need to use this class later to add the db context to services.
Do I have to use generics to achieve this? I would prefer pass in the type, and use this to configure AddDbContext.
This is what I got so far.
DB class:
public class DB<TContext>(string connectionStringName = "Default") where TContext : DbContext
{
    public string ConnectionStringName => connectionStringName;

    public TContext Context => TContext; // ?? what to return?
}

This is how I need to use the data:
var db = GetDB(); // uses an instance of DB<TContext>

builder.Services.AddDbContext<db.Context>(opt => {
    opt.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString(db.ConnectionStringName));
});

Is it clear what I mean? I just need to pass in a type who inherits DbContext and later use this type to  configure AddDbContext().
If there's another way to do this please tell me, I'm kinda stuck on the generic path.

You need to go all in on using the DI service container. Injecting the context as a constructor argument.

If I am understanding the question correctly, you will need to provide a concrete instance of the generic type:
public class DB<TContext>(
    TContext context,
    string connectionStringName = "Default")
    where TContext : DbContext
{
    public string ConnectionStringName => connectionStringName;

    public TContext Context => context;
}


I ended up creating a whole new configure method. Not ideal, but it works..
public static void AddAssetsDbContext<TDbContext>(WebApplicationBuilder builder, string connectionStringName) where TDbContext : DbContext
{
    builder.Services.AddDbContext<TDbContext>(opt => { 
       opt.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString(connectionStringName)); 
    });
}

In use:
AssetsConfig.AddAssetsDbContext<LEContext>(bld)
    .AddAssets(
        new GDPR("LE", "Index"),
        new DefaultRoute("LE", "Index"),
        new Service(typeof(IDataRepo), typeof(DataRepo)),
        new Service(typeof(IPictureListRepo), typeof(PictureListRepo)),
        new Service(typeof(ILESiteHelper), typeof(LESiteHelper)),
        new Minify(MinifyTargets.Production));

